# Azure Update Management showing superseded versions of Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation, azure-security

I've been having this issue with multiple Azure Virtual Machines for a while now.

I'm using and Azure Automation Account / Log Analytics Workspace to manage updates on 5 different Azure Virtual Machines. It's routinely showing all machines as missing updates, specifically multiple superseded copies of *'Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602'*

See screenshot below where it's showing versions 1.321.1221.0 through 1.321.1256.0 as missing:

[Screenshot of Update Management blade in my Automation Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smFFc.png)

However all five Virtual Machines have 1.321.1260.0 installed as shown here:

[Screenshot of 'View Update History' from affected Virtual Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWSeG.png)

I know that the Update agent has refreshed since 1.321.1260.0 was installed as 1260.0 was previously showing as missing, however as per the screenshot above it is now not.

I have tried to clear the current cache and trigger an update from CMD using the following script [as detailed here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/defenderupdates):

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender
MpCmdRun.exe -removedefinitions -dynamicsignatures
MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate
```

This runs and completes successfully, but doesn't resolve my issue.

Can anyone suggest why these superseded updates are showing, and/or how to clear them out? They are adversely affecting my otherwise squeaky clean Azure Security Center posture.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the resolution.

> When a superseded update becomes 100 percent not applicable, you
> should change the approval state of that update to Declined. To change
> approval state for all your updates:
>
> 1. In the Automation account, select **Update Management** to view machine status. See [View update assessments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/update-mgmt-view-update-assessments).
> 2. Check the superseded update to make sure that it's 100 percent not applicable.
> 3. Mark the update as declined unless you have a question about the update.
> 4. Select **Computers** and, in the **Compliance** column, force a rescan for compliance. See [Manage updates for VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/update-mgmt-manage-updates-for-vm).
> 5. Repeat the steps above for other superseded updates.
> 6. Run the cleanup wizard to delete files from the declined updates.
> 7. For Windows Server Update Services (WSUS), manually clean all superseded updates to refresh the infrastructure.
> 8. Repeat this procedure regularly to correct the display issue and minimize the amount of disk space used for update management.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/update-management#scenario-superseded-update-indicated-as-missing-in-update-management

Comment: I've just re-read all that again and none of it specifically states exactly **how** to mark an update as declined?